# Xamarin Android Weekly repeating Alarm is not firing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am trying to schedule Weekly notification. For a specific day and time, repeated weekly But it is not working. Here is my code for scheduling alarm

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", task.Id, hour, minutes));
var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
intent.PutExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationId, id);
intent.PutExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationMessage, $"{context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.general_push_reminder_body)} {task.Name}");
intent.PutExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationTitle, context.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.general_push_reminder_title));

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.Instance;
calendar.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, (int)day);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, minutes);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Second, 0);

if (calendar.Before(Calendar.Instance))
{
    Log.Info("Task", $"Adding 7 days as scheduled time is past");
    calendar.Add(CalendarField.DayOfYear, 7);
}
var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 7 * AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingIntent);
```

Here is my receiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info("Task", $"Alarm manager received");
                var title = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationTitle);
                var message = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationMessage);
                var id = intent.GetIntExtra(AndroidConstants.NotificationId, 0);
                Log.Info("Task", $"Showing Notification with id {id} {title} and {message}");
                NotificationHandler.ShowNotification(context, id, title, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Task", ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

There is no exception. I have tried several options but the `AlarmReceiver` is not firing at all.

If I select today's day and give time after current time, still the `if block for adding time for past` is fired and an extra 7 day is added.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is in `alarmManager.SetRepeating(...)`.

If you see the docs of [Android.App.AlarmManager.SetRepeating](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.AlarmManager.SetRepeating/) it states that the second parameter:

> triggerAtMillis: time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

You are passing `calendar.TimeInMillis` which according to the docs gives you:

> the current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch

which is not what you want.

I'd rather not use `Calendar` and use `DateTime` instead because it's easier to use and do the difference between the desired datetime and the current datetime in milliseconds, i.e.:

```
// here I hardcode the values but you should set whatever you want or get it from the user
DayOfWeek desiredDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
int desiredHour = 1, desiredMinute = 30, desiredSecond = 0;

// Calculate which will be the desired date time in which the alarm will go off for the first time
var differenceInNumberOfDaysBetweenDayOfWeek = desiredDayOfWeek - DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
var nextDayOfWeek = differenceInNumberOfDaysBetweenDayOfWeek >= 0
                        ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(differenceInNumberOfDaysBetweenDayOfWeek)
                        : DateTime.Today.AddDays(differenceInNumberOfDaysBetweenDayOfWeek + 7);
var desiredDateTime = new DateTime(nextDayOfWeek.Year, nextDayOfWeek.Month, nextDayOfWeek.Day, desiredHour, desiredMinute, desiredSecond);

// this are the milliseconds left to arrive to the desired date time for the alarm to go off
var desiredMillisToArriveToDateTime = (desiredDateTime - DateTime.Now).Milliseconds;

var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, desiredMillisToArriveToDateTime, 7 * AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingIntent);
```

HIH

Comment: With this code the alarm fires few minutes before the time specified. I have checked some Android java codes and found that `calendar.TimeInMillis` is how it has been done. By the way I found another problem in my code. C# DayOfWeek and Android DayofWeek did not have same int value. Android DayOfWeek value starts from 1 whereas C# it is 0. I fixed that problem. With that fix, I am getting the alarms but it is never in exact time.

Comment: I'd check how many milliseconds is it giving and which are the real number of milliseconds to wait so that the time to go off the alarm is right

Comment: I have checked those. They are exactly same. May be it's regarding how Android OS handles scheduled alarm based on battery usage, cpu usage etc.